# Polars Dataframe- Remove duplicate rows based on one column

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I would like to only include unique values in my polars Dataframe, based on one column.
In the example below I would like to create a new dataframe with only uniques based on the "col_float" column.

Before:

```
┬───────────┬──────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
┆ col_float ┆ col_bool ┆ col_str    ┆ col_date   │
┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
┆ f64       ┆ bool     ┆ str        ┆ date       │
╪═══════════╪══════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
┆ 10.0      ┆ true     ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 2020-01-01 │
┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
┆ 20.0      ┆ false    ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 2020-01-01 │
┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
┆ 20.0      ┆ true     ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 2020-01-01 │
┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
┆ 40.0      ┆ false    ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 2020-01-01 │
┴───────────┴──────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

after:

```
┬───────────┬──────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
┆ col_float ┆ col_bool ┆ col_str    ┆ col_date   │
┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
┆ f64       ┆ bool     ┆ str        ┆ date       │
╪═══════════╪══════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
┆ 10.0      ┆ true     ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 2020-01-01 │
┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
┆ 20.0      ┆ false    ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 2020-01-01 │
┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
┆ 40.0      ┆ false    ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 2020-01-01 │
┴───────────┴──────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

(Notice the third row getting dropped because col_float was not unique)

Intuitively, one of my attempts was:

```
let mut df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "col_float": [10.0, 20.0, 20.0, 40.0],
        "col_bool": [True, False, True, False],
        "col_str": pl.repeat("2020-01-01", 4, eager=True),
    };
let mut df2=DataFrame::new(vec![&df[0]]).unwrap();

df= df.unique(df2,UniqueKeepStrategy::First);
```

but got:

```
expected `Option<&[String]>`, found `DataFrame`
```

Which was to be expected beforehand of course.

I'm not sure whether im using to right function and if I do, how this subset should be passed. Searching the documentation or github did not help me as in the examples or code only "None" was passed as the subset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seemed less of an polars related question, but more related to my experience with Rust.

Working example:

```
let mut df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "col_float": [10.0, 20.0, 20.0, 40.0],
        "col_bool": [True, False, True, False],
        "col_str": pl.repeat("2020-01-01", 4, eager=True),
    };
df= df.unique(Some(&["col_float".to_string()]),UniqueKeepStrategy::First);
```